# Sitecore DropTree field render in JSS layout service API

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, layout-service, renderfield

I am using DropTree field and I selected the listing page Item. so now I want to see the selected item full path in the layout service API.

**Actually Layout Data**

```
"componentName": "latestEvents",
"dataSource": "{610FFB59-3607-4072-8674-0C6B6CAB26AE}",
"params": {},
"fields": {
"rootItem": 
"id": "73847c43-b411-4ad5-b95e-0a12784fc7d3",
"url": "/en/eventlisting",
"name": "EventListing",
"displayName": "EventListing",
},
```

**Expecting Layout Data**

```
"componentName": "latestEvents",
"dataSource": "{610FFB59-3607-4072-8674-0C6B6CAB26AE}",
"params": {},
"fields": {
"rootItem": {
"id": "73847c43-b411-4ad5-b95e-0a12784fc7d3",
"url": "/sitecore/content/Sites/WebSite1/home/eventlisting",
"name": "EventListing",
"displayName": "EventListing",
},
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Saiprasath change root path and start item in sitedefinition config file and change language embedding from true to false